# JOOQ combining Field and SortField in orderBy method?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-order-by, jooq

I'm trying to select a list of random records from a MySQL-table but with priority towards certain ENUM types. It works fine when I run the following plain SQL-query in a terminal:

```
select * from table_name where expires <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()*1000 
order by enum_type desc, rand() limit 500;
```

But I get a compilation error from my IDE when writing the following code:

```
private List<FooRecord> getNextRecordsWeighted(Condition condition, int recordLimit) {
    final long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return context.selectFrom(TABLE_NAME).where(TABLE_NAME.EXPIRES.lessOrEqual(timeNow)).
        orderBy(TABLE_NAME.ENUM_TYPE.desc(), DSL.rand()).limit(recordLimit).fetch();
}
```

Now, what my IDE says is that there obviously is no compatible method that I can call for doing this. How would I go about to solve this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `orderBy()` methods' various overloads. You have:

- [`SelectOrderByStep(Field, Field)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectOrderByStep.html#orderBy-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-)
- [`SelectOrderByStep(SortField, SortField)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectOrderByStep.html#orderBy-org.jooq.SortField-org.jooq.SortField-)

Your `TABLE_NAME.ENUM_TYPE.desc()` is a `SortField`, whereas `DSL.rand()` is a `Field`. In order to make this work, you'll have to make `DSL.rand()` a `SortField`, by calling: `DSL.rand().asc()`.

I recognise that this is somewhat of a flaw in the API, which can probably be fixed in a future version of jOOQ. I have created a GitHub issue for this fix: [#3631](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3631)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Alas, I ran into another problem. Could you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: @TheShahin: You're welcome. Note: The way how Stack Overflow works is that you ask one question per problem. This will make it much more easy for future visitors to know what's going on when they find this question via Google. So best remove your edit again, and paste it into a new question. I'll answer there (or perhaps someone else)

Comment: Noted. I've removed my edit. I solved the problem by writing a raw SQL-string embedded into the jOOQ-query. It works, though it's not pretty, but I don't have time to change it due to a deadline :) Again, thank you.

Comment: @TheShahin: Fair enough. I'll be looking out for jOOQ questions here on Stack Overflow, so if it pops up again, feel free to ask another one.